# Add caching to static html website on Azure

Tags: azure, caching, iis

I have a static html website hosted on Azure. This is pure html and css. No back-end whatsoever. So I'm assuming it's run in IIS. That might be wrong, but I assumed it was.

I want my images and css to be cached. So I added a web.config in the img folder. But now I get an internal server error.

If I don't add the web.config, it works.

This is [the working site](http://www.redstar.be) with it's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/petermorlion/RedStarITSite). Notice that in the [build/images/web.config file](https://github.com/petermorlion/RedStarITSite/blob/master/build/images/web.config), I've put the caching part in comment.

And this is the [broken site](http://betaredstarit.azurewebsites.net) and the same [web.config](https://github.com/petermorlion/RedStarITSite/blob/caching/build/images/web.config). Notice on this version of the site, the image doesn't load. If I navigate to [the image](http://betaredstarit.azurewebsites.net/images/logo.png), I get the error.

So I guess my question is, is it possible to make IIS on Azure add the necessary caching header to requests for static resources in a certain folder?

[The IIS site](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) makes me believe it should be possible. But in my case I'm using a Web App in Azure, so maybe that complicates matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put web.config inside web root, and then use location to apply caching for certain folder.

<strike>See web app deploy: http://tobevitaltest.azurewebsites.net/</strike>.
Forked repo is here: https://github.com/longchiwen/RedStarITSite